# How can I prevent my page from being reloaded when linking to an anchor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a couple of anchors on my page which look like this:

```
<a ng-href="#1363219200000">03/14/2013<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

Further down the page I have an anchor like:

```
<a id="1363219200000" class="tableAnchor" href=""></a>
```

Now when I click the first link, the page will be reloaded. Then, it will jump to the anchor (thanks to me using [`$anchorScroll();`](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.%24anchorScroll)). However, I really don't see why the page is being reloaded.

I've read about [ngHref](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHref) but the example don't really make any sense to me. No matter which way I try it, the page is always reloaded.

Comment: Can you use onclick rather than href? (i.e. omit href altogether).

Comment: @Westie: I guess whatever works would be fine. I just assumed this would be the most straight-forward approach.

Comment: TBH I thought that it would have been fine with an empty href.  Tne other option, I suppose, is to put a # in the href (`href="#"`), but this forces an addition to the history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should utilize the [`reloadOnSearch`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/dc0b0c77c7ba3e419442ec639356ab5d3ba7efbe) property of the route to avoid the reload.

Something like:

```
    when( "/meetings", {
            templateUrl   : "partials/meetings",
            controller    : MeetingController,
            reloadOnSearch: false
          } ).
```